# Generate all length-n permutations of True/False?

Tags: python, boolean, permutation

This problem came up while trying to write code for a truth-table generating function.

How can I generate a list of lists of all length-n permutations of True and False? In other words, given a list of elements `[True, False]`, how can I generate all permutations of all possible length-n combinations of those elements?

For example:

`n=2` length-2 permutations are:

```
[[True, True], [True, False], [False, True], [False, False]]
```

`n=3` the length-3 permutations are:

```
[[False, False, False],[False,False,True],
[False,True,False],[False,True,True],
[True,False,False],[True,False,True],[True,True,False],[True,True,True]]
```

I know there's 2^n lists in this list. I also have considered using `itertools.product`, but that only seems to give **permutations of a specific combination**. In this case, I think I want to generate permutations of ALL  combinations of a length-n list of true/false.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking...

Comment: @U9-Forward sorry,  I'm not that good at wording things. I added another example.

Comment: There are other functions in the `itertools` module.

Comment: Are you sure this is permutation? A permutation is "each of several possible ways in which a set or number of things can be ordered or arranged". [True, True, True] is not a rearrangament of True and False values.

Comment: @KM142646 and Zabop I would rather prefer to say "Cartesian product of the set {True, False}, n times with itself", I agree that the requested list of lists is not the same as the set of permutations of the set {True, False} (the permutation set has only 2 elements; {True, False} and {False, True}).

Comment: These are **not permutations**. This is the Cartesian product of a list (`[True, False]`) with itself `n` times.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [False, True]
>>> list(itertools.product(l, repeat=3))
[(False, False, False), (False, False, True), (False, True, False), (False, True, True), (True, False, False), (True, False, True), (True, True, False), (True, True, True)]
>>>
```

And if you want the to change the tuples inside the list to sublists, try a list comprehension:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [False, True]
>>> [list(i) for i in itertools.product(l, repeat=3)]
[[False, False, False], [False, False, True], [False, True, False], [False, True, True], [True, False, False], [True, False, True], [True, True, False], [True, True, True]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

It's relatively easy if you consider the values to be *bits* instead. Like for the `n = 3` case, see it as a value containing three bits.

Loop (using integers) from `0` to `2ⁿ - 1` (inclusive) and print all bits in each value (with `0` being `False` and `1` being `True`). Then you will have all permutations.

Of course, it's not a very Pythonic solution, but it's generic.

Comment: Wow, didn't even think one bit about using binary. Very interesting.

Comment: You've one me :D (Don't like that pun? Two bad)

Answer (score 3):

Try [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with the `repeat` argument:

```
In [1]: from itertools import product

In [2]: product([True, False], repeat=2)
Out[2]: <itertools.product at 0x1c7eff51b40>
```

As you can see above, it returns an iterable, so wrap it in `list()`:

```
In [3]: list(product([True, False], repeat=2))
Out[3]: [(True, True), (True, False), (False, True), (False, False)]

In [4]: list(product([True, False], repeat=3))
Out[4]:
[(True, True, True),
 (True, True, False),
 (True, False, True),
 (True, False, False),
 (False, True, True),
 (False, True, False),
 (False, False, True),
 (False, False, False)]

In [5]: list(product([True, False], repeat=5))
Out[5]:
[(True, True, True, True, True),
 (True, True, True, True, False),
 (True, True, True, False, True),
 (True, True, True, False, False),
 (True, True, False, True, True),
...
```

It also returns a list of tuples instead of a list of lists, but that should be fine for most use cases and can be solved very easily with a list comprehension if lists are really needed:

```
[list(tup) for tup in mylist]
```

Answer (score 2):

And if you want list of lists, not list of tuples, start with [U9-Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8708364/u9-forward)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059999/8565438):

```
import itertools
l=[False,True]
ll=list(itertools.product(l,repeat=3))
```

and continue:

```
lll=[]
for each in ll:
    lll.append([EACH for EACH in each])
```

`lll` will be a list of lists, instead of tuples.

---

Much better way, following comments:

```
[list(elem) for elem in lll]
```

Thanks to [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6740022/kevin-moy).

Comment: That's not best way.

Comment: please share a better one, I am also interested

Comment: Look at mine then. It's simpler too :D

Comment: I would think just `[list(elem) for elem in listTuples]` would convert it appropriately

Comment: @zabop in my answer.

Comment: @KevinMoy I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not efficient solution but you can use:

```
def permuteBool(n, l):
...      if n==0:
...         return l
...      return [permuteBool(n-1, l+[True])] + [permuteBool(n-1, l+[False])]
... 
>>> permuteBool(3, [])
[[[[True, True, True], [True, True, False]], [[True, False, True], [True, False, False]]], [[[False, True, True], [False, True, False]], [[False, False, True], [False, False, False]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Looks like I didn't check the output before posting my answer. It'll stay as it is as the right way would be a duplicate answer of the correct answer.

Use this simple code:

```
>>> import itertools  # library of magic
>>> length = 3        # length of your wanted permutations
>>> result = itertools.combinations(    # combinations based on position
...     [*[True, False] * length],      # generates the items needed
...     length                          # length of the wanted results
... )
>>> print([list(r) for in result])
[[False, False, False], [False, False, True], [False, True, False], [False, True, True], [True, False, False], [True, False, True], [True, True, False], [True, True, True]]
```

Comment: SyntaxError at `(True for _ in range(length),`

Comment: I've fixed it. Phew, that took a lil bit.

Comment: Still SyntaxError, missing comma.

Comment: This is why I'm supposed to be in bed right now :D So sleepy haha.

Comment: last line should be: [list(r) for r in result], otherwise syntaxerror

Comment: So what you want is, imo:


    import itertools  # library of magiclength = 3        # length of your wanted 
    permutations
    length = 3 
    result = itertools.combinations(    # combinations based on position
        [*[True, False] * length],       # generates the items needed
        length                          # length of the wanted results
    )
    [list(r) for r in result]

Comment: Even with the `r` typo fixed, [this prints something completely wrong and completely different from what you claim it prints](https://ideone.com/xZhOuz).

Comment: `combinations` is the wrong tool for this job. At best, you can get something that overgenerates combinations and uses `set` to fix things, which is still horribly inefficient comparing to using `product`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple recursive list program

```
def list_exponential(n,set1=[]):
if n == 0:
    print(set1)
else:
    n-=1
    list_exponential(n, [False]+set1)
    list_exponential(n, [True]+set1)

list_exponential(5)
```

Sample output

```
$ python3 exponential.py 5
[False, False, False, False, False]
[True, False, False, False, False]
[False, True, False, False, False]
[True, True, False, False, False]
[False, False, True, False, False]
[True, False, True, False, False]
[False, True, True, False, False]
[True, True, True, False, False]
[False, False, False, True, False]
[True, False, False, True, False]
[False, True, False, True, False]
[True, True, False, True, False]
[False, False, True, True, False]
[True, False, True, True, False]
[False, True, True, True, False]
[True, True, True, True, False]
[False, False, False, False, True]
[True, False, False, False, True]
[False, True, False, False, True]
[True, True, False, False, True]
[False, False, True, False, True]
[True, False, True, False, True]
[False, True, True, False, True]
[True, True, True, False, True]
[False, False, False, True, True]
[True, False, False, True, True]
[False, True, False, True, True]
[True, True, False, True, True]
[False, False, True, True, True]
[True, False, True, True, True]
[False, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True]
```